# Is it possible to run git commands from inside R script?

Tags: r, git, system

Below is the description of a traditional work flow in git.

Is it at all possible to somehow write a script inside R that would make git execute all of it?
And would it even be advisable to do something like this?
Thank you very much!

1. Create/modify files in your project directory.
2. From the command line, change directory by entering `cd <path_to_local_repository>`.
3. Enter `git add --all` at the command line to stage the changes.
4. Enter `git commit -m '<commit_message>'` at the command line to commit changes to the local repository.
5. Enter `git push`  at the command line to push your changes to your remote repository (e.g., on Bitbucket).
6. If prompted for authentication, enter your Bitbucket password.

Comment: Why would you do that? RStudio supports git (don't know if Bitbucket is supported).

Comment: I'm not very proficient at git but sometimes I want to force push because R Studio gives me errors I don't fully understand, and that are solved by a force push. I don't think RStudio supports this, so in this case I use `shell` to run the `git` commands from *R*.

Comment: @Roland Because I want it to happen automatically - without user's involvement. The names of the files being staged/committed/pushed would always be the same. The authentication would be the same. And I don't care about customizing the commit message in this case.

Comment: @user3245256 Regardless of the fact that you *can* of course do this in R the question is: why R? Why not a shell script, which in your case sounds much more appropriate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Honestly, because the only thing I know is R, and I don't know anything about shell scripts and how to run them from R...?

Answer (score 5):

The 'git2r' package provides this kind of functionality: https://docs.ropensci.org/git2r/reference/checkout.html

Creating files/dirs and changing directory can be done in base R using file.create and setwd etc

Then:

```
git2r::add(repo = ".", path = NULL, force = FALSE)
git2r::commit(repo = ".", message = "commit message")
git2r::push(credentials = whatever-you-need-for-pushing-to-bitbucket)
```

Comment: Note that you can use `git2r::commit(all=TRUE, message="blah")` to add and commit all files, as requested by OP.